# SPeL Regular expression that returns substring rather than boolean value

Tags: java, regex, xml, spring, javabeans

Is there a way to as a SPeL expression that returns the matching substring of source string rather than if it contains the regular expression?

For example,

```
<property name="emailValid" 
          value="#{user.email matches '^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(.[A-Za-z]{2,})$'}"/>
```

will return the boolean value of if user.email matches the regex

However what I'm looking for is something like
(if `test.url="helloworld/iwantthispart"`)

```
<property name="theNewSubstring" 
              value="#{test.url imaginaryMethod '[^\/]+$'}"/>
```

And afterwards the property `thenNewSubstring` will be equal to `iwantthispart`

I'm also using Spring, if there are any gems in the framework that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in spring Expression languate there str only>, <, >=, <=, instanceOf, matches and between operators.

You can write in spring xml code like:

```
boolean value = parser.parseExpression("T(java.util.regex.Pattern).compile('.*').matcher('abc').matches()").getValue(Boolean.class);
```

Or extract group that you need from matcher.